# Kiel oni tradukas "Memento mori" al Esperanto?

Tags: translation

Nu, mi konas aliajn tradukaĵojn al la [hispana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori), [angla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori), ktp., kaj ĉiuj estas ege malsamaj inter ili (laŭ mi). Mi supozas, ke la ĝusta kaj ekzakta senco el la latina frazo varias en ĉiu lingvo sed tio malhelpas al la ĝusta kaj korekta tradukado de ĉi tiu frazo.

Nun, mi deduktas, ke la plej simpla tradukaĵo de tiu latina frazo al  Esperanto estus:

> *Rememoru, ke vi mortos.*

Sed tiu ne konvinkas min.

Comment: Se vi preferas uzi komon, ĝi devus esti antaŭ *ke*.

Comment: Vi pravas, @AndrewWoods. Dankon.

Comment: @AndrewWoods Ĉu uzado de komoj estas preferaĵo?

Answer (score 7):

Mi skribus *Memoru, ke vi mortos* aŭ *Memoru vian mortemon*. Sed fiksa  esprimo laŭ mi ankoraŭ ne ekzistas.

Answer (score 6):

Kial tiu ne konvinkas vin? Vi certe povas trovi pliajn proponojn, kiel "rememoru vian mortecon" sed via propono ŝajnas pli taŭga al mi.

Answer (score 5):

Angle, "memento mori" estas uzata kiel substantivo. Do, mi tradukis la lokucion, "memorigilo de morteco".

Answer (score 3):

Mia sugesto estas simple:

> *Memoru morton.*

Pri *Respice post te; hominem te memento*:

> *Rigardu malantaŭen; vian homecon memoru.*

Comment: Mi ial deziras meti la «la»: «memoru la morton». Alikaze ŝajnas al mi ke vi volas ke mi pensu pri iu ajn specifa morto, ne pri la ĝenerala koncepto. Ĉu tio estas fuŝa penso?

Comment: Tiu penso eble ne estas fuŝa, sed tro bazas sin sur lingvoj kiuj havas ankaŭ nedifinan artikolon kaj tiel estas malsimilaj al Esperanto. Eble vi egaligas, ekzemple, la vorton _morto_ al _a death_. Cetere, proverboj kaj proverbecaj esprimoj nature emas esprimiĝi koncizege. _Memoru morton_ estas bona traduko.

Answer (score 3):

Nur por aldoni: Ni iam faris podkastan epizodon pri [*Memento Mori*](https://kern.punkto.info/2015/11/26/kp054-memento-mori/). Mi ne memoras, ĉu ni diskutis eblan esprimon Esperantan.